# ReactNative - Drawer Navigator with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

Is it possible for a drawer navigator (reactnavigation v2) not to change screen but a redux state instead ?

**Example:**

```
api = [{id: 1, name: 'Pippo'}, {id: 2, name: 'Pluto'}, {id: 3, name: 'Paperino'}]
```

Drawer

```
Menu title 1
Menu title 2
Menu title 3
```

Screen

```
Welcome **state.name**
```

Click Element 1 --> actionChangeName(element_1) --> state name = 'pippo'

```
 Screen -> Welcome Pippo
```

Click Element 2 --> actionChangeName(element_2) --> state name = 'pluto'

```
 Screen -> Welcome Pluto
```

Click Element 3 --> actionChangeName(element_3) --> state name = 'paperino'

```
 Screen -> Welcome Paperino
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem:

I create a drawerNav with only a screen that contain "Welcome **state.name**" with a contentComponent called **DrawerMenu**

```
createDrawerNavigator({ main: WelcomeScreen }, { contentComponent: DrawerMenu })
```

DrawerMenu (example):

```
class DrawerMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}> Drawer Menu </Text>
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
          {this._renderList()}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _renderList = () => this.props.list.map(element => (
    <TouchableOpacity key={element.id} onPress={this._updateElementSelected(element.id)}>
      <Text>Menu title {element.id}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  _updateElementSelected = (elementId) => () => {
    this.props.actionSetElementSelected(elementId, this.props.list);
    this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
  };
}
```